# sqlite_3 Last Insert rowid

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am working with an SQLite database on iOS, but I cannot figure out how to get the last inserted row ID. The sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() function only works with the current connection, so it is useless if i have just opened the database.

In C#, I am used to calling `ExecuteScalar()` with the SQL query `SELECT last_insert_rowid()`. Is there a way to do this using sqlite3?

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM some_table` ?

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, you can only use it on the same db connection:

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html